# Row operations for matching information from dataset dictionary/metadata into the main set

Tags: r, purrr

I was provided with a large data set which had a very complex set of metadata. All the munging was done using tidyverse tools, like janitor, dplyr, etc. But in order to add the age and gender to the main set I resorted to a small loop of the type:

```
tbl$age <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(tbl)) {
    if (is.na(tbl$age[i])) {
        a <- tbl$id[i]
        b <- as.character(metadata[match(a,metadata$id),c("age")])
        tbl$age[i] <- as.numeric(b)
    }
}
```

Please refer to the MWE:

```
metadata <- tribble(
    ~id, ~gender,  ~age,
    "AA1001", "male",  3.6,
    "BB2191", "female",  8.5
)


tbl <- tribble(
    ~id,    ~B,  ~C,
    "AA1001",    0,  2,
    "AA1001",   24,  2,
    "AA9798",    0,  0,
    "AA1007",    0,  2,
    "AA1007",   24,  2,
    "AA1007",   48,  2,
    "AA1025",    0,  2,
    "AA1025",   24,  2,
    "AA1025",   48,  2,
    "AA4405",    0,  0,
    "AA6683",    0,  0,
    "BB4498",  NA,  0,
    "BB2191",    0,  0,
    "AA1086",    0,  0,
    "AA1086",   24,  0,
    "AA1086",   48,  0,
    "AA8352",    0,  0,
)
```

- Is it possible to achieve the same result as the small for loop, but using row manipulation with purrr or other tool within the tidyverse?

The expected output:

```
> tbl
# A tibble: 17 x 4
   id         B     C   age
   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 AA1001     0     2   3.6
 2 AA1001    24     2   3.6
 3 AA9798     0     0  NA  
 4 AA1007     0     2  NA  
 5 AA1007    24     2  NA  
 6 AA1007    48     2  NA  
 7 AA1025     0     2  NA  
 8 AA1025    24     2  NA  
 9 AA1025    48     2  NA  
10 AA4405     0     0  NA  
11 AA6683     0     0  NA  
12 BB4498    NA     0  NA  
13 BB2191     0     0   8.5
14 AA1086     0     0  NA  
15 AA1086    24     0  NA  
16 AA1086    48     0  NA  
17 AA8352     0     0  NA
```

Comment: Also, try with `left_join` `left_join(tbl, metadata[c('id', 'age')])`

Comment: Updated to fix errors and expected output. The warnings can be ignored.

Comment: Try with `left_join` should get the output

Comment: Yes, @akrun, it indeed works. However, if I used by = it fails... Strange. Thank you. Wanna answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done more easily with `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(tbl, metadata[c('id', 'age')])
```

---

If the column that is used for joining is the same name, then `by` should work

```
left_join(tbl, metadata[c('id', 'age')], by = "id")
```

If it differs in name, i.e. 'idA', 'idB', use `by = c('idA' = 'idB')`